# How to create a simple model to output the double of input value?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm a newbie at ML and I'm struggling with a model.

In order to try to understand what was wrong with a bigger model, I wanted to create a simple one which goal is just to provide the double value of the input, but I couldn't succeed even in this simples problem, since the model compile but doesn't learn.

Can someone please help me? I'm just frustrated since I have no clue why this simples model cannot learn.

````
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

x = [i for i in range(1, 21)]
y = [2 * i for i in range(1, 21)]
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=1))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, shuffle=True, epochs=10, validation_data=(x, y))```
````

Comment: best practice questions belong on [codereview.se] as they are opinion question which means they are off-topic for SO

Comment: i mentioned the loss function, but I'm not asking for the best one. I just want to make the model learn.

Comment: @TheGrandJ The description makes it sound like the code is not working correctly (i.e. "_I couldn't succeed even in this simples problem_"), which would make the post off-topic on Code Review. When directing users there please ask them to first read the help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_".

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I do see what you are saying but they quite literally say "Can someone please help me? **I don't know if I'm using the *best activation and loss functions for this problem***, but I just wish to make the model to learn." so that would be a code review question. And that seems to be the most important aspect based on the help me statement.

Comment: @TheGrandJ I'm sorry man, but that's just not what I wanted to ask. It's my first time asking something in SO. I'm gonna delete this part of the question.

Comment: My apologies then. I will remove my flag. Thank you for taking the time to improve your question. I don't often see that many take comments into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you used a ReLU activation function, which results a derivative of 0 for the parameter. A linear activation function will solve the problem. it fits well:)

You could also try altering the initializer for the parameter somehow.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

x = [i for i in range(1, 21)]
y = [2 * i for i in range(1, 21)]
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=1))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation=None))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, shuffle=True, epochs=100, validation_data=(x, y))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I still don't get it... now the loss is reducing over ephocs, but the accuracy doesn't improve, it just prints "accuracy: 0.0000e+00". Do you have any clue of the reason?

Comment: @viniciusAbrantes Because this isn't a classification problem, an accuracy can't exist.

Comment: @viniciusAbrantes Good luck in learning ML! Please mark the question as answered.